# GNU Parallel: suppress warning when input is read from terminal

Tags: gnu-parallel

When input is read from terminal, GNU Parallel always displays a warning:

```
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

But sometimes I do want to read from terminal (e.g., when I'm copy & pasting stuff from elsewhere entry by entry). Is it possible to turn off this warning? I couldn't find such an option in `man parallel` or `man parallel_tutorial`.

Note that I don't want a cheap solution like `2>/dev/null`, since warning messages from other programs will be turned off, too. For instance, consider the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function print12 () {
    echo "printing $1 to stdout"
    echo "printing $1 to stderr" >/dev/stderr
}
export -f print12

SHELL=/bin/bash parallel -k print12 2>/dev/null
```

Messages printed to `stderr` will all be suppressed.

---

Just realized that I can do a `cat` or some `read </dev/tty` to achieve my desired effect. But let's just focus on the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be turned off. But see it as a praise: Since you are doing it on purpose, you are an expert (at least in the eyes of GNU Parallel).

As it is just a warning, you are free to paste your arguments and have them run: The warning does not stop GNU Parallel from reading your input.

If you *really* do not like the warning:

```
cat | parallel ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know it runs without problem (just annoying to see false positives), and I'm aware of the `cat` trick (see last line of original question). I'll take the praise then...

Comment: @ole-tange, a method to prevent parallel from pausing a script to wait for input when there is no input would be useful. I have some processes that may or may not produce input for parallel to use. Clearly I can write an if statement in bash to circumvent parallel from running without input but it would be nice if parallel had a flag to continue when no input.

Comment: @conteh Not really sure what you mean. Example?

Comment: @ole-tange... right so I might have something like parallel  "java -jar saxon9ee.jar -s:blank.xml -xsl:xslt.xsl  path=XML/{1}" ::: $(find -name "*.xml")   but that .xml input might not always be produced by the process because the output is optional earlier in the scripts processes. So without surrounding the parallel code with an if statement, the process will then stop with the parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose.   So a flag to allow parallel to continue without requesting input in such cases would be a nice improvement.

Comment: Here: find -name "*.xml" | parallel "java -jar saxon9ee.jar -s:blank.xml -xsl:xslt.xsl path=XML/{1}"